# Another way of passing orderby list in pyspark windows method

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I just had a below concern in performing window operation on pyspark dataframe. I want to get the latest records from the input table with the below condition, but I want to exclude the for loop:

```
groupby_col = ["col('customer_id')"]
orderby_col = ["col('process_date').desc()", "col('load_date').desc()"]

window_spec = Window.partitionBy(*groupby_col).orderBy([eval(x) for x in orderby_col])

df = df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(window_spec))
df = df.filter(col('rank') == '1')
```

My concern, is I'm using the orderby_col and evaluating to covert in columner way using eval() and for loop to check all the orderby columns in the list.
Could you please let me know how we can pass multiple columns in order by without having a **for loop** to do the descending order??

Comment: Any other solution ??

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
groupby_col = ["col('customer_id')"]
orderby_col = ["col('process_date')", "col('load_date')"]

window_spec = Window.partitionBy(*groupby_col).orderBy(f.desc(*orderby_col))

df = df.withColumn("rank", f.rank().over(window_spec))
df = df.filter(col('rank') == '1')
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the above approach, but getting error as below:
**TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**
at the orderby_col using with **"*"**.